# leaftletjs-adding points dynamically and draw line string

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I am trying to draw the path of a flight using leafletjs and geojson. I'll be getting the geometry from a stream.
this is what I have done so far:

```
    let index = 0;
    let geoJsonLayer;
    let intervalFn = setInterval(function () {
        let point = trackData.features[index++];

        if(point) {

            let coords = point.geometry.coordinates;
            coords.pop();
            coords.reverse();

            geoFeature.geometry.coordinates.push(coords);
            if(map.hasLayer(geoJsonLayer)) map.removeLayer(geoJsonLayer);

            geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson(geoFeature, {
                onEachFeature: (feature, layer) => {
                    const content = feature.properties.title;
                    layer.bindPopup(content);
                }
            });
            geoJsonLayer.addTo(map);
            // console.log(coords);

        } else {
            clearInterval(intervalFn);
        }
    }, 100);
```

setInterval is to simulate the part whereby I get the geometry from a stream.

now when a user clicks on the path I need to show some properties of the path, and I am trying to use the onEachFeature for that, but its not working correctly.
I suspect its because I am removing the layers (I did this to improve the performance)

Is there any other better ways to do what I am trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably try [`addLatLng()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#polyline-addlatlng)

> Adds a given point to the polyline.

Your `geoFeature` sounds to be a single Feature, so your `geoJsonLayer` will contain a single layer (polyline):

```js
let myPolyline;

geoJsonLayer.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    myPolyline = layer; // Will be done only once actually.
});

// When you receive a new point…
myPolyline.addLatLng([lat, lng]);
```

With this you should not have to remove your layers every time.

The popup should therefore stay open, if it is shown.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/3v7hd2vx/265/ (click on the button to add new points)

Comment: in your fiddle example you are using only polyline and not using geojson. I will be using more features when different tracks come into play. could you modify your example to show how to do it with geojson ?

Comment: @ShathishKumar This sounds like it should be a new question, with more details about your data structure. Furthermore, you should be careful about the data structure you will receive from your stream.